# Number of ways to answer three questions, with four choices each, and not get all of them right

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have this question, I could not get answer to it.

> In an examination there are three multiple choice questions and each question has $4$ choices. Number of sequences in which a student can fail to get all answers correct is...

Here is my opinion:
The total number of answering a question correctly is $4^3$. Of all the $4^3$ combinations only $1$ way or selection of choices is the correct answer. So I have subtracted $1$ to get final answer which is $63$. But I am wrong, answer is $123$.

Comment: Is it required that the student answers at all? They could leave some or all of the answers blank, which should increase the number of possible combinations, which might solve your problem, but maybe I'm making a wrong assumption...

Comment: The only way I can think of getting $123$ is if we are allowed to leave a one or two questions blank, but not all three.

Comment: But how come, there are no multiple choices if I put 63 I am done

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right, which somehow makes the question somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I think the "natural" interpretation is that all questions are attempted, giving OP's $63$. But it should not be a matter of interpretation, the question should be explicit.

Comment: my friends is 63 a right answer. If student doesn't leave a blank question